# hide and show in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

i wana show and hide div on click event and i want to do that it from one button. i write a code but it is not working.

```
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      $(function () {
         $('#clickme').click(function () {

            $('.mydiv').hide();
         })

         $('.clickme').click(function () {

            $('.mydiv').show();
         })
      })
   </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="mydiv">hiiiii</div>
   <input type="button" id="clickme" value="clickme" />
</body>
```

Comment: pls dont refer me toggle function i want to do that from hide and show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<div id="divContent">Some content</div>
<input type="button" id="btnShow" value="Hide" />
```

**Script**

```
$(function(){
    var isVisible=true;
    $("#btnShow").click(function(){
         if(isVisible)
         {
              $(this).val("Show")
              $("#divContent").hide();
         }
        else
        {
             $(this).val("Hide")
             $("#divContent").show();
        }
        isVisible=!isVisible;   
    });    
});
```

Here is the working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/95vXQ/5/

**EDIT :**

```
isVisible = !isVisible
```

The above line is a simplified version of the below code

```
if(isVisible)
{
  isVisible =false;
}
else
{
 isVisible =true;
}
```

Comment: your code is working fine but can u tell me why we use isVisible=!isVisible; in bottom of the cod

Comment: @amit : That is to swap the value of `isVisible` variable. that means if the value was true, it will become false and vice versa. This vaiable value we use to deter mine what is the text on the button (Show or Hide).

Comment: so this =! sign is for swapping value

Comment: @amit : yes for swapping the value without an if else

Comment: Amit, =! is not swapping. The ! is applied to the variable `isVisible` and not to the equals sign. Code written like this could help you clarify it `isVisible = !isVisible`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$('#clickme').click(function() {   // you're using an ID here!
    var div = $('.mydiv');

    if(div.is(":visible")) {
        div.hide();
    } else {
        div.show();
    }

});
```

You are adding two event listeners to your button. Both will run on click, therefore the div will be shown and instantly hidden.

Comment: your answer is correct but i wana to it from hide and show method

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">


$(function(){

$('#clickme').click(function(){

    if ($('.mydiv').is(":visible")) {
        $('.mydiv').hide();
    }
    else {
        $('.mydiv').show();
    }
}
)
})


</script>


</head>

<body>

<div class="mydiv">hiiiii </div>
<input type="button" id="clickme" value="clickme" />
</body>
```

Answer (score 3):

You are mixing class and id identifiers in your jQuery. Your button has ID clickme. In the first code where you are hiding the contents your are referencing a button in a proper way, but in the second script you are using class .clickme instead of #clickme.

Although correct, this script will hide and show at the same time, and for that reason it will appear as if nothing has happened:

```
$(function(){ 
   $('#clickme').click(function(){ 
       $('.mydiv').hide(); 
   });

   $('#clickme').click(function(){ 
       $('.mydiv').show(); 
   }); 
});
```

A better approach is to use:

```
$(function() {
    $("#clickme").click(function() {
        $(".mydiv").toggle();
    });
});
```

As Binarous pointed out, the first script, although correct, will not work. You should apply some custom class when hiding and use that class when showing, or even better use toggle() function.

Comment: True, I realized that as well. Thanks.

Comment: Toggle is the way to go here. If you want a slide effect, you can use http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Answer (score 2):

Add a class to your div when you are hiding it, remove when you are showing it, and check it before you want to do something.

This code works:

```
$(function(){
    $('#clickme').click(function(){

        if ($('.mydiv').hasClass("hidden")) $('.mydiv').removeClass("hidden").show();
        else $('.mydiv').addClass("hidden").hide();
    });
})
```

Here is a working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/V3gRH/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
    $("#clickme").click(function(){
      var $mydiv = $(".mydiv");
        if ($mydiv.css("display")=="none"){
           $mydiv.show();   
        } else
        {
           $mydiv.hide();
        }
    });        
});​
```

[**-- SEE DEMO --**](http://jsfiddle.net/Curt/VXMaN/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('#clickme').click(function() {
        if ($('.mydiv').css('display') == "none") {
            $('.mydiv').show();
        } else {
            $('.mydiv').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you could make a hidden checkbox.
 after button click it would be checked-true  . then check IF you click the button again, it would check if it is checked ( if it is checked - Uncheck)..
so then you could add another IF.. on button click, check IF checkbox is checked, if it is show, else hide..

OMG chikidi check yourself

$('#check').is(:checked) {...}
$('#check').not(:checked) {...}

It is stupid but i might work! ;D